# How can create a new table from another after Calculate Some Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table called `WorkSpace` with 4 columns.

Each record in this table refers to their parent record through the `Parent_id` column.

You should continue this cycle until you reach the main parent and all of these steps specified in the `View_Parent_id` column.

The ID of main parent number is specified by 1.

So now I want create a `NEW_WorkSpace` table and separate each of the values in `View_Parent_id` column into a separate column.

The `View_Parent_id` column is ultimately 15 value so we need 15 columns in new table (Level_1...Level_15).

I used the loop in my query but it was very slow.

`WorkSpace` table has 1.5 million rows.

`WorkSpace` table:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+------------------+
| W_ID| Title | Parent_id | View_Parent_id   |
+-----+-------+-----------+------------------+
| 1   |   AAA |    null   | null             |
| 2   |   BV  |    1      | 1                |
| 3   |   CX  |    2      | 1+2              |
| 4   |   DSO |    2      | 1+2              |
| 5   |   ER  |    3      | 1+2+3            |
| 6   |   ER  |    5      | 1+2+3+5          |
| ... |  ...  |    ...    | ...              |
| 1000|   MNV |    1      | 1                |
| 1001|   SF  |    1000   | 1+1000           |
| 1002|   EDD |    1000   | 1+1000           |
| 1003|   YSG |    1001   | 1+1000+1001      |
| 1004|   RPO |    1003   | 1+1000+1001+1003 |
+-----+-------+-----------+------------------+
```

`NEW_WorkSpace` table:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-----+----------+
| ID  |  W_id | Parent_id | Level_1 | Level_2 | Level_3 | ... | Level_15 |
+-----+-------+-----------+---------+-------- +---------+-----+----------+
| 100 |   1   |    null   | AAA     |         |         | ... |          |
| 101 |   2   |    1      | AAA     |  BV     |         | ... |          |
| 102 |   3   |    2      | AAA     |  BV     |         | ... |          |
| 103 |   4   |    2      | AAA     |  BV     |  CX     | ... |          |
| 104 |   5   |    3      | AAA     |  BV     |  CX     | ... |          |
| ... |   ... |    ...    | ...     |  ...    |  ...    | ... |  ...     |
+-----+-------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-----+----------+
```

My code:

```
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @W_ID decimal(20, 0);
    DECLARE @parent_id decimal(20, 0);

    DECLARE @Level1 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level2 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level3 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level4 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level5 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level6 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level7 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level8 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level9 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level10 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level11 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level12 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level13 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level14 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @Level15 nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @titles_tmp nvarchar(MAX);

    DECLARE @cont_spilit_tittle int;
    DECLARE @parent_titles_tmp nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @cont_tmp int;
    DECLARE @cont int;

    SELECT @cont = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.WorkSpace ;
    SET @cont_tmp = 0;

    WHILE (@cont_tmp < @cont)
    BEGIN  
        SET @W_ID = (SELECT dbo.WorkSpace.W_ID FROM dbo.WorkSpace  
                     ORDER BY W_ID ASC OFFSET @cont_tmp ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @parent_id = (SELECT dbo.WorkSpace.parent_id FROM dbo.WorkSpace 
                          ORDER BY W_ID ASC OFFSET @cont_tmp ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @titles_tmp = (SELECT dbo.WorkSpace.title FROM dbo.WorkSpace 
                           ORDER BY W_ID ASC OFFSET @cont_tmp ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @parent_titles_tmp = (SELECT dbo.WorkSpace.parent_titles FROM dbo.WorkSpace 
                                  ORDER BY W_ID ASC OFFSET @cont_tmp ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL 
             DROP TABLE #MyTempTable

        SELECT IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS 'RowID', * 
        INTO #MyTempTable 
        FROM StringSplitXML(@parent_titles_tmp, '+')

        INSERT INTO #MyTempTable 
        VALUES (@titles_tmp)

        SET @cont_spilit_tittle = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #MyTempTable)

        IF(@cont_spilit_tittle < 0)
            SET @cont_spilit_tittle = 1

        WHILE (@cont_spilit_tittle < 15)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #MyTempTable VALUES ('')
            SET @cont_spilit_tittle = CAST(@cont_spilit_tittle AS INT) + 1
        END

        SET @Level1 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                       ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level2 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                       ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level3 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                       ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level4 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                       ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level5 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                       ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level6 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                       ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level7 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                       ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 6 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level8 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                       ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 7 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level9 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                       ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 8 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level10 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                        ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 9 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level11 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                        ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level12 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                        ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 11 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level13 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                        ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 12 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level14 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                        ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 13 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
        SET @Level15 = (SELECT Value FROM #MyTempTable 
                        ORDER BY RowID ASC OFFSET 14 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)


        INSERT INTO [].[dbo].[NEW_WorkSpace]
           ([W_ID], [parent_id],
            [Level1], [Level2], [Level3], [Level4], [Level5],
            [Level6], [Level7], [Level8], [Level9], [Level10],
            [Level11], [Level12], [Level13], [Level14], [Level15])
        VALUES (@W_ID, @parent_id,
                @Level1, @Level2, @Level3, @Level4, @Level5,
                @Level6, @Level7, @Level8, @Level9, @Level10,
                @Level11, @Level12, @Level13, @Level14, @Level15) 

        SET @cont_tmp = CAST(@cont_tmp AS INT) + 1
    END  

    RETURN
END
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please show us your attempt

Comment: @squirrel Code added.

Comment: as you mention pivote but there is no pivote concept looking your code as well as your output ??

Comment: @nits-patel I was just guessing it might be the solution to pivote but I didn't write it myself

Comment: Why are you using a `WHILE` here?

Comment: @larnu I said I was just guessing it might be the solution

Comment: @larnu actually I used loop While because I have to separate each field in each row but it was very slow.

Comment: Yes, because a `WHILE` is one of the worst ways to do anything in SQL; it's not a programming language. A `WHILE` in a query language is going to be inherently slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this using string operations on `view_parent_id`.  Then aggregating the final result:

```
with cte as (
      select w_id, parent_id, view_parent_id,
             0 as lev, convert(varchar(max), concat(view_parent_id, '+', w_id, '+')) as parents 
      from t
      union all
      select w_id, parent_id, view_parent_id,
             1 + lev, 
             convert(int, left(parents, charindex('+', parents) - 1)),
             stuff(parents, 1, charindex('+', parents), '')
      from cte
      where parents <> ''
     )
select w_id, parent_id, view_parent_id,
       max(case when lev = 1 then parent_title end) as title_1,
       max(case when lev = 2 then parent_title end) as title_2,
       max(case when lev = 3 then parent_title end) as title_3,
       max(case when lev = 4 then parent_title end) as title_4,
       max(case when lev = 5 then parent_title end) as title_5
from (select cte.*, t.title as parent_title, count(*) over (partition by cte.w_id) as cnt
      from cte join
           t
           on t.w_id = cte.parent
      where lev > 0
     ) cte
group by w_id, parent_id, view_parent_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e8f58b6a8ec0f023cb77775716472b9e) is a db<>fiddle.

As for processing.  Probably the most expensive part of the query is the aggregation after the recursive CTE.  The recursive portion is not doing any joining, so it should be fairly fast (string operations can be slow).

The join to get the label is using correct types, so an index on `w_id` can be used.

Comment: Hello Mr Linoff I should say as always your answer helped me but I think you forgot some part of my question. Actually the answer is correct and too fast but you missed last level in each record.

Comment: @JavadAbedi . . . That is easily fixed by adding the current `w_id` to the parents list.  However, it seems that that column should just have the complete path including the current node.  In any case, I adjusted the answer and you can see it in the db<>fiddle.

Comment: Yes you right I added w_id to the parent list. This answer solved my problem. Thank you so much Mr Linoff.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this ugly and assumes you have a max of 15 levels, and your expected results are wrong; as I have `W_ID` `4` has a value of `'DSO'` for `Level_3`, but your expected results has `CX`, even though that row isn't linked to `CX` in any way.

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (W_ID int NOT NULL,
                            Title varchar(3) NOT NULL,
                            Parent_id int NULL,
                            View_Parent_id varchar(100) NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES (1,'AAA',NULL,NULL),
       (2,'BV',1,'1'),
       (3,'CX',2,'1+2'),
       (4,'DSO',2,'1+2'),
       (5,'ER',3,'1+2+3'),
       (6,'ER',5,'1+2+3+5');

GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT (YT.W_ID + 99) AS ID,
           YT.W_ID      ,
           YT.Parent_id,
           Title AS level_1,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_2,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_3,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_4,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_5,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_6,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_7,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_8,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_9,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_10,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_11,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_12,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_13,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_14,
           CONVERT(varchar(3),NULL) AS Level_15,
           1 AS [Level]
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
    WHERE YT.Parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (YT.W_ID + 99) AS ID,
           YT.W_ID,
           YT.Parent_id,
           r.Level_1,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 1 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_2 END AS Level_2,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 2 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_3 END AS Level_3,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 3 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_4 END AS Level_4,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 4 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_5 END AS Level_5,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 5 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_6 END AS Level_6,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 6 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_7 END AS Level_7,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 7 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_8 END AS Level_8,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 8 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_9 END AS Level_9,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 9 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_10 END AS Level_10,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 10 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_11 END AS Level_11,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 11 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_12 END AS Level_12,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 12 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_13 END AS Level_13,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 13 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_14 END AS Level_14,
           CASE r.[Level] WHEN 14 THEN YT.Title ELSE r.Level_15 END AS Level_15,
           r.[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         JOIN rCTe r ON YT.Parent_id = r.W_ID)
SELECT r.ID,
       r.W_ID,
       r.Parent_id,
       r.Level_1,
       r.Level_2,
       r.Level_3,
       r.Level_4,
       r.Level_5,
       r.Level_6,
       r.Level_7,
       r.Level_8,
       r.Level_9,
       r.Level_10,
       r.Level_11,
       r.Level_12,
       r.Level_13,
       r.Level_14,
       r.Level_15
FROM rCTE r;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd9273f52634c4df7a91cae4d3e8dc28)

Comment: Thank you for your help, My problem solved  but it was very slow. please vote to my question.

Comment: Hierarchical data will always be slow with large data sets. If performance is a big deal, use a `hierachyid`, @Javadadebi . I'm not sure wha you mean by vote your question, are you asking me to up vote it?. If this does solve this solve the problem, you should be marking this as the solution, so that future readers know the answer was helpful.

Comment: yes you right. I don't no why some people down vote to some question anyway your answer is too close but I should say it's too slow for example for 100 record it's take 20 sec imagine about 1.5 M record.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Then you should have a look at your indexes. If it takes 100 seconds for 100 rows you have some seriously poorly indexed tables, or a severely under hardwared server.

Comment: As for the downvote, I suspect it was before you added your attempt. Only the downvoter could tell you though.